# Reproducing "SQL Tables" in Classes

Tags: c#, sql, oop, reference

I've got a set of classes `City`, `Country`, `Border`.

Each class has references to each other:

- **City** references the parent **Country**
- **Country** references the cities contained via **`List<City>`**
- **Country** references other bordering countries via **`List<Country>`**
- **Country** references a **Border** class, shared between 2 Country instances

---

I think the above is causing some problems within the program I'm using: slow loading and memory problems.

I'm not quite sure what is going on exactly. I've been reading that "circular references" are bad practice. Is there another way to map an SQL-like class pattern to regular classes?

I really want to avoid having to call a method `public City GetCities(){...}` as there will likely probably be 120000 of these calls a second. So I need these to be `cached` rather than dynamically requested.

---

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: use link to object for that. by this you will never face memory problems for that

Comment: It could be a good scenario to use the flyweight pattern... Just populate cities once from the database and access to it using the flyweight factory.

Comment: Table Border has some column (besides, obviously, the two primary-foreign key) or this table is only composing a many to many relationship?

Comment: @sourabhdevpura link? I'm not sure I'm familiar with what you mean.  I assume it's neither requesting the object dynamically via something like LINQ or a reference.

Comment: @RadiantHex Sorry it's my mistake it LINQ

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi Border contains others variables as well e.g. area, isopen. Kind of like an SQL many to many relationship table.

Comment: @sourabhdevpura if there was a way to `cache` LINQ like a regular ORM would do, I would happily consider that :)

Comment: @HuorSwords thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look into it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like whatever you're using to access items from the database is performing far too much fetching, and that you have duplicate objects all over the place.

Is the data in the tables small enough to cache entirely? If so, you can preload everything into dictionaries when the application starts, then query those for the relationships instead.